# Determine if two squares on a chessboard are the same color - Codefights

Tags: java, switch-statement, boolean, boolean-logic, chess

I have been struggling to figure out why my code isn't returning correct results on the CodeFights chessBoardCellColor arcade challenge.

> Given two cells on the standard chess board, determine whether they have the same color or not.

The inputs are given as two digit strings made up of one uppercase letter A-H followed by one number 1-8.

```
    boolean chessBoardCellColor(String cell1, String cell2) {    
        return isWhite(cell1)==isWhite(cell2);
    }

    boolean isWhite(String digits){
        boolean state1=false; 
        boolean state2=false;
        boolean white = false;
        char[] digs = digits.toCharArray();
            switch(digs[0]){
                case 'A': state1=true;
                case 'C': state1=true;
                case 'E': state1=true;
                case 'G': state1=true;
                default : state1=false;}
            switch(digs[1]){
                case '1': state2=true;
                case '3': state2=true;
                case '5': state2=true;
                case '7': state2=true;
                default : state2=false;}
        if(state1==state2){white=false;}
        else{white=true;}
        return white;
        }
```

I've been going over this for a few hours and I cannot see where I went wrong. Forgive me if its a totally obvious problem that I'm missing.

Comment: Fly through it with a debugger and see if the values correspond to what you think they should be.

Comment: @notyou interestingly, when I copy into browxy.com everything is returning false, whereas in the codefights browser app, some sets of data return true and some do not... What debugger would you suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add `break` after every `case xx`, for example:

```
case '1': state2=true; return;
```

otherwise the program will continue to the last `default`, and `state1` & `state2` will always be `false`.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ChkltLabs No problem :). And I suggest to use TheJavaGuy-Ivan Milosavljević's solution. It looks more clean.

Comment: Its a good looking solution to be sure, but I feel I would not improve if I just copied someone else's work. I was seeking the fault in my own logic moreso than a more elegant solution to the problem. I want to get better, not just get good grades.

Comment: @ChkltLabs Of course, I believe you will get better and better :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the logic is more complicated than it needs to be. I would check first the column and then the row. Something like this:

```
public final class Chess {
    public boolean isBlack(String field) {
        char[] digs = field.toCharArray();
        return (isOddColumn(digs[0]) && isOddRow(digs[1])) || (isEvenColumn(digs[0]) && isEvenRow(digs[1]));
    }

    public boolean isWhite(String field) {
        return !isBlack(field);
    }

    private boolean isOddColumn(char col) {
        return col == 'A' || col == 'C' || col == 'E' || col == 'G';
    }

    private boolean isEvenColumn(char col) {
        return col == 'B' || col == 'D' || col == 'F' || col == 'H';
    }

    private boolean isOddRow(char row) {
        return row == '1' || row == '3' || row == '5' || row == '7';
    }

    private boolean isEvenRow(char row) {
        return row == '2' || row == '4' || row == '6' || row == '8';
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Chess app = new Chess();
        System.out.println(app.isBlack("A1"));
        System.out.println(app.isBlack("B2"));
        System.out.println(app.isBlack("C3"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> > ...determine whether they have the same color or not.
>
> ```
> boolean chessBoardCellColor(String cell1, String cell2)
> ```

You do not need to know colors, you need to know are they *the same*:

```java
boolean isSameColor(String square0, String square1) {
    return
    (Character.codePointAt(square0, 0) + Character.codePointAt(square0, 1)) % 2 ==
    (Character.codePointAt(square1, 0) + Character.codePointAt(square1, 1)) % 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this more clearly:

```
private static final String ROW = "12345678";
private static final String COL = "ABCDEFGH";

boolean myIsWhite(String loc) {
    // A row's leftmost square is white every other row starting at 1.
    boolean rowStartsWhite = (ROW.indexOf(loc.charAt(1)) % 2) == 0;
    // They then alternate
    boolean cellIsWhiteIfRowStartsWhite = (COL.indexOf(loc.charAt(0)) % 2) == 0;
    return rowStartsWhite ? cellIsWhiteIfRowStartsWhite : !cellIsWhiteIfRowStartsWhite;
}

public void test(String[] args) {
    for(int r = 0; r < ROW.length(); r++) {
        for(int c = 0; c < COL.length(); c++) {
            String loc = ""+COL.charAt(c)+ROW.charAt(r);
            boolean isWhite = myIsWhite(loc);
            System.out.println("Loc = "+loc+" is "+(isWhite?"White":"Black"));
            if(isWhite != isWhite(loc)) {
                System.out.println("You were wrong with this one.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
/**
 * @function chessBoardCellColor
 * @param {String} cell1
 * @param {String} cell2
 * @return {Boolean}
 */

function chessBoardCellColor(cell1: string, cell2: string): boolean {
  return Math.abs((cell1.charCodeAt(0) - cell2.charCodeAt(0))) % 2
    === Math.abs((cell1.charCodeAt(1) - cell2.charCodeAt(1))) % 2;
}
```